# My php callback is printing random html source code

Tags: php, json

I have a post request which querys a database and is supposed to return an array of objects. When i return this in json format it will not let me JSON.parse because the return content includes the whole html shell for the webpage, i am unsure why this is. is there anything i could be missing. Here is my code:

getLogins.php

```
    $servername= "localhost";
    $sql_username = "root";
    $sql_password = "";
    $dbname = "website_login";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $sql_username, $sql_password, $dbname);

    $sql = "select * from login;";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        
      array_push($loginInfo, array("Username"=> $row["Username"],"Password"=> $row["Password"] , "First_name"=> $row["First_name"], "Second_name"=> $row["Second_name"], "Email"=> $row["Email"]));
      echo json_encode($loginInfo);
    }
    
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

login.php

```
  $("#loginButton").on("click", login);


  function login() {

    $.post("getLogins.php", function(responseData){
      console.log(responseData);
      let logins = JSON.parse(responseData);
      console.log(logins);
    });
    
  }
  

</script>
```

Comment: These cannot be your files: php files have activation codes to tell PHP that everything between those codes is PHP code and not just literal text. But if these _are_ literally your files: start them with `<?php` and optionally end them with `?>` (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php for more details).

Comment: By default PHP claims the output it is sending is HTML. If you are sending JSON then say so with `header("Content-Type: application/json");` and jQuery will respect that are parse the JSON automatically. (You still need to ensure your script doesn't output any HTML).

Comment: `json_encode` generates a complete JSON text. Don't use it inside a loop. Two JSON texts next to each other are not valid JSON and you will get parsing errors. Generate an array then convert the array to JSON *after* the loop.

Comment: `"Password"=> $row["Password"]` sending passwords to the client is a very bad sign. You should probably read https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: Thank you for the info I am just focusing on the general passing of JSON between client and server and I realise passing passwords may be bad practice. I am a bit of a beginner when it comes to web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> because the return content includes the whole html shell for the webpage

Because that is what *getLogins.php* generates (even if you haven't shown us all of *getLogins.php*.

PHP doesn't stop sending all the data outside `<?php ... ?>` just because the request was initiated by JavaScript instead of traditional browser navigation.

If you want to design an API, then design an API. The server-side code should *only* output the data you want to output.

If you have code that generates HTML inside *getLogins.php*, remove it. If your wrapper is being added because you are using the [front controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) pattern then exclude your API endpoints from it.

Comment: Ah I see very silly mistake from me thank you for your comment. I am not fully sure on how echo works I was under the impression it would just send the contents of the variable and nothing else. Are there any resources that could help me understand this better. Thanks again

Comment: `echo` *does* send you the contents of the expression on its right hand side and nothing else. It's the rest of your code that is outputting the HTML.

Comment: Could you explain what it is that causes it to output the html please I’m not sure I understand

Comment: Also for future reference should I be uploading full files so it can be understood better

Comment: @LTreadwell49 — I gave two possibilities in the answer. As I said, it isn't the code you've shown us.

Comment: As per [ask] you should be providing an [mcve] (which is not the *full* file, but it is enough to reproduce the problem).

Comment: Okay thank you, sorry I didn’t make it clear before but it was the html tags around the php that was the problem so you hit the nail on the head. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not just random HTML but an error instead?

Check the error by adding these lines to the top of your code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then, read the response yourself instead of attempting to parse it.

From what I can see, the variable **$loginInfo** could be the problem as it is not declared and you are attempting to push another array to it

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you have not actually provided the full `getLogins.php` file, which makes this difficult.

However, if the code you provided is at the very beginning of the actual `getLogins.php` file, if you were to place a `die();` statement at the end (just after your call to `mysqli_close($conn);`), that *should* do the trick.

It looks like there are other errors with your code as well, but hopefully this can get you pointed in the right direction :)

Comment: Thank you for the reply although my main focus is on the question at hand could you point out the other errors if you get the chance please. I am trying to learn as much as possible haha

Comment: We would really need to see the actual code file in order to do that.

Comment: oh okay nevermind i thought you meant errors within the code that i have displayed. From the feedback i realised the php was echoing the html shell i had put around it. I am still unsure why this occurs.